# Twitter followers list not getting

Tags: android, twitter

I know twitter api update to 1.1 and i have get successfully token & tokenSecret

I have checked both api

https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=myscreenname

response getting

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=myscreenname

response getting

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Please help me to get Response of Followers ids list.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to execute your request (`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=myscreenname`) in [dev console](https://dev.twitter.com/console) and it works like a charm.

Seems like you've missed the authorization step (autorization **with OAuth** is required for api v1.1), so verify that you authorized with valid credentials.

You can read more about [auth on twitter here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) or check out documentation for library that you are using to make api requests.

Comment: also run that Api but still getting same response

Comment: @AnkitMakwana now quite sure that I've understood correctly. Your problem is that you are using api v 1.1 and unable to make request (getting "Bad Authentication data" error). Is this correct?

Comment: Ok. Try this: go to dev console (see my post for url), pick "OAuth 1" in "Authentication" combobox, perform auth on twitter, and try to make your request through dev console. What happens?

Comment: here i m getting but in app its not working, so authentication issue may be right

Comment: Cool. Your next step seems to be adding auth in your application. You haven't mentioned this in your question but you are probably want to use something like twitter4j to make requests to twitter (to handle all signing/auth stuff and more). If that is the case - you can peek at this tutorial: http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/quick-tutorial-twitter-processing If not - you'll have to mess with signing your requests with OAuth token by hands.

Comment: Oops, ignore the link I gave - it is for old api version. Anyway. check out twitter4j to see how to manage Oauth authorization and do actual requests.